# Entity Framework on primary key and is null

Tags: entity-framework

I need to map some external database, I can't modify the schema. But the tables don't have primary key but rather columns like `Client_ID`, `Calendar_ID` but they are not null and entity can map them, much worse is if these columns in few tables can be null, then Entity Framework throws an error that it can't be mapped.

My question is: can I somehow disable entity tracking and map these tables without primary key and with columns as null?

Or can I use code-first approach, does it let me to create and map class with no primary key and all columns as is null?

Comment: Perhaps you can create a view over this tables to avoid null values. Something like  `select * from clients where Client_ID is not null`. Then you can map the view.

Comment: @danihp i can't modify this db, this is external db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework must have a key field in order to work. It doesn't have to be a true primary key in the database but it needs to be unique. If you have tables that have a nullable field and no true primary key and you can't modify the database then maybe Entity Framework isn't the best fit for this project. It might work if you never try and load the entities with the null values, but it will throw errors when you do (as you have noticed).